# Git syntax error in bitbucket pipelines: "failed to push some refs to MY_USERNAME"

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a weird git error where I see my password and username in the error messages, so apparently there is a syntax error, but I can't figure it out.

I am running `git push` as one of the steps in Bitbucket Pipelines. The command is this:

```
git push https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASSWORD@my-app-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/my-app.git development:master
```

The error I get from Bitbucket Pipelines is this:

```
error: src refspec <my actual password>@my-app-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://<my actual username>:'
```

Why am I seeing my username and password in the error messages? It seems the branch name is not picked up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double check you don't have a space as the first character of your AZURE_PASSWORD environment variable? The URL syntax looks right to me. So it's the only thing I think could be a factor. (This would cause it to separate the URL into two tokens)

As for the environment variables showing, have you marked them as 'secured' variables? This will mask the value, preventing it from being output in the logs. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html

Comment: That was the problem. Not a space actually, it was a non-printable character that appeared there during copy-pasting.